# PHP Array Iteration to Flatten All Possible Results

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I don't know the term of what I am trying to do, so I can't seem to find a similar answer.

I'm trying to make an array that looks like the following:

```
array (
'birds' => array(
      'parakeet',
      'conure',
      'woodpecker'),
'color' => array(
      'red',
      'blue',
      'green'
 ),
 'size' => array(
       'large',
       'medium',
       'small'
 ));
```

to iterate through all possible permutations to look like the following

```
   array(
      array('parakeet','red','large'),
      array('parakeet','red','medium'),
      array('parakeet','red','small'),
      array('parakeet','blue','large'),
      array('parakeet','blue','medium'),
      array('parakeet','blue','small'),
      array('parakeet','green','large'),
      array('parakeet','green','medium'),
      array('parakeet','green','small'),
      array('conure','red','large'),  
      ..... etc 
   );
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a step down loop on each level for bird, color and size. Then create a temporary container and continually merge it:

```
$data = [[]]; // initialize empty container
foreach ($arr as $key => $values) {
    $tmp = []; // store it in here
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $tmp[] = array_merge($d, [$value]); // then continually merge
        }
    }
    $data = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, your solution was simple and clean! I appreciate the help. I just couldn't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @Dyluck sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through what you need to, and build a new array as you go:

```
$newarray = $temparray = array();

foreach ( $oldarray['birds'] as $bird )
{
   $temparray[] = $bird;
   foreach ( $oldarray['color'] as $color )
   {
      $temparray[] = $color;
      foreach ( $oldarray['size'] as $size )
      {
          $temparray[] = $size;
      }
      $newarray[] = $temparray;
      unset ($temparray);
   }
}
```